# Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance in Angularjs modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap ui modal which is working fine but when I try to close it using modalInstance it gives above error.Here is my code

```
  var app = angular.module('LoginModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('LoginModal', ['$scope',  '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
    $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: '/app/template/Login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            size: size
        });
    }
}]);
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$http', function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.loading = {
        state: false
    }
    $scope.errors = '';
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.cancel = function () {

        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

I have created the cancel function in the controller which I specify with the template still it gives error.I use ng-click="cancel()" in button inside LoginController .
Need help?

Comment: Are you specifying controller in your view as well using ng-controller? It seems so

Comment: ng-controller="LoginController" , ng-controller="LoginModal" yes like this modal is opening and I am seeing error in console

Comment: See my answer. You should not use ng-controller with LoginController, since there is no real provider for $modalInsatnce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are instantiating the controller with ng-controller directive in the modal view. Instead you only need to use `controller` option of the modal in order to get the special dependency `$modalInstance` injected. If you have instantiated controller using `ng-controller="LoginController"` you need to remove it and you would not need it as well as the controller would automatically be instantiated (by resolving special dependency `$modalInstance`) and attached to the template.

Comment: controller="LoginController" like this?

Comment: @Ghazanfar You are already doing it in your modal settings. `controller: 'LoginController',` So just remove ng-controller="LoginController" from `/app/template/Login.html`